# Input Error: There is no script engine for file extension ".log"

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I get this error when I run a SAS program and a python program in a batch file.

```
Input Error: There is no script engine for file extension ".log".
```

I have found out that because it is being scheduled by Task Scheduler, the error is coming from the `os.getcwd()` 
that I have in my python program.

I am simply creating a log folder from where the code is running and since it is being ran from Task Scheduler, I don't know where it is being created and it even gives an error. When I hardcode and replace the `os.getcwd()` to an actual path in my laptop. For ex: `C:\My folder\\`, the error disappears.

How can I overcome this issue other than hardcoding a path in python?
It is to be noted that if I run the batch file manually with the os code, it works as expected. It is just being handled differently by **Task Scheduler**

Comment: Perhaps you should be using `sys.path[0]` instead of `os.getcwd()`, as the current working directory is not the same as the path holding the running script. In fact your task scheduler will probably be running with the well protected `\Windows\System32\ ` directory as current.

Comment: I have used the start directory from task scheduler. With this the os.getcwd() will start on that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the optional textbox which says **'Starts in (Optional)'** in the Task Scheduler -> Edit Action Setting

I would enter the path of where my python script are located so any folder or file created, it will start in this directory.